# SELECT function in KQL?

Tags: kql

I'm trying to store a single, string value in a column into a variable in KQL.

Like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN2 = 'value'
```

here is my KQL query:

```
AuditLogs
| extend GroupName = tostring(TargetResources[0].displayName)
| extend ObjectID = tostring(TargetResources[0].id)
| where Category has "Management"
| where GroupName startswith_cs "XYZ"
```

The above query works

I want to store the value from column *ObjectID* into a variable.
I need to perform a second query within the same table based on the variable.
Let's pretend the variable's name is *ObjectID*, like the column it was extracted from above. like this:

```
AuditLogs
| where Category has "Management" and OperationName has "Add member to group"
| extend ObjectID2 = tostring(TargetResources[1].id)
| extend UPN = tostring(TargetResources[0].userPrincipalName)
| where ObjectID2 == ObjectID
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  **(1)** Please share a data sample + required results. **(2)** Please share the whole challenge and not just a piece of it, to avoid the [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding right, you can use `let` to do that. So your complete query would look something like:

```
let foundID = AuditLogs
| extend GroupName = tostring(TargetResources[0].displayName)
| extend ObjectID = tostring(TargetResources[0].id)
| where Category has "Management"
| where GroupName startswith_cs "XYZ"
| project ObjectID;
AuditLogs
| where Category has "Management" and OperationName has "Add member to group"
| extend ObjectID2 = tostring(TargetResources[1].id)
| extend UPN = tostring(TargetResources[0].userPrincipalName)
| where ObjectID2 in (foundID)
```

A few things to note here:

- Projecting `ObjectID` in the first query.
- The semicolon after `let` to tell Kusto where the first query ends.
- Using `where ObjectID2 in (foundID)` as the last clause in case
  several IDs are returned. If you're sure there's only going to be
  one, you can use something like `where ObjectID2 == toscalar(foundID)`.

Answer (score 1):

A join table should solve it

`AuditLogs     | extend GroupName = tostring(TargetResources[0].displayName) | extend ObjectID = tostring(TargetResources[0].id) | where Category contains "Management" | where GroupName startswith_cs "XYZ" | join kind=inner (AuditLogs | where Category contains  "Management" and OperationName contains  "Add member to group" | extend ObjectID2 = tostring(TargetResources[1].id) | extend UPN = tostring(TargetResources[0].userPrincipalName) ) on $left.ObjectID == $right.ObjectID2`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
let ObjectId = toscalar(
AuditLogs
| extend GroupName = tostring(TargetResources[0].displayName)
| extend ObjectID = tostring(TargetResources[0].id)
| where Category has "Management"
| where GroupName startswith_cs "XYZ")
;
AuditLogs
| where Category has "Management" and 
        OperationName has "Add member to group"
| extend ObjectID2 = tostring(TargetResources[1].id)
| extend UPN = tostring(TargetResources[0].userPrincipalName)
| where ObjectID2 == ObjectID
```